# Getting problems in saving data in a database with as3

Tags: mysql, sql, actionscript-3, flash

I have created a simple app to save and load data in a flash file using a database with only two fields (id (autoincrement) and name). The database is called `test1` and has a table entitled `test` with two fields `id` and `name`.

When I try to save just a simple value I get the message

> INSERT error: SQLError: 'Error #3115: SQL Error.', details: `'no such table: 'test''`, 
>   operation:'execute', detailID:'2013' event.error.message: Error #3115: SQL Error. event.error.details: `no such table: 'test'`

I have already created the db and I save it in the same folder with the Flash (`.swf`) file.

This is the code I use:

```
import fl.data.DataProvider;
import flash.data.SQLResult;
import flash.data.SQLConnection;
import flash.filesystem.File;
import flash.data.SQLStatement;
import flash.data.SQLConnection;

var conn: SQLConnection;
var createStmt: SQLStatement;
var insertStmt: SQLStatement;
var insertStmt2: SQLStatement;
var selectStmt: SQLStatement;

var insert1Complete: Boolean = false;
var insert2Complete: Boolean = false;

loadBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, getData);
SaveBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addData);
init();

function init(): void {
    conn = new SQLConnection();
    trace("opening database");
    var dbFile: File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("test1.db");
    conn.openAsync(dbFile);
}

function addData(event: MouseEvent): void {
    trace("Adding data to table");
    insertStmt = new SQLStatement();
    insertStmt.sqlConnection = conn;
    var sql: String = "";
    sql += "INSERT INTO test (id, name)";
    sql += "VALUES ('John')";
    insertStmt.text = sql;
    insertStmt.execute();
}


function getData(event: MouseEvent): void {
    trace("Loading data");
    selectStmt = new SQLStatement();
    selectStmt.sqlConnection = conn;
    var sql: String = "SELECT id, name";
    selectStmt.text = sql;
    selectStmt.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, selectResult);
    selectStmt.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, selectError);
    selectStmt.execute();
}

function selectResult(event: SQLEvent): void {
    trace("Data loaded");
    selectStmt.removeEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, selectResult);
    selectStmt.removeEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, selectError);
    var result: SQLResult = selectStmt.getResult();
    resultsGrid.dataProvider = new DataProvider(result.data);
}

function selectError(event: SQLErrorEvent): void {
    status.text = "Error loading data";
    selectStmt.removeEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, selectResult);
    selectStmt.removeEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, selectError);
    trace("SELECT error:", event.error);
    trace("event.error.message:", event.error.message);
    trace("event.error.details:", event.error.details);
}
```

Comment: Looks like you need to create a table first.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But i have already created the database with a table named test with two fields. I created with a free program called "DB Browser for SQLite".

Comment: Do you actually need it to be an SQL database? There are other, **simpler** means to load/save data. You might be over-complicating things with such a solution.

Comment: @user2653677 What happens when you open it synchronously vs asynchronously? How soon are you calling your addData function?

Comment: You mean shared object or Xml? I thought sql was the only solution.

Comment: @user2653677 **SharedObject** is the simplest way to save persistent data on client's device, just like browser cookies. If it is AIR app on Android/iOS, you don't even need (I think) user's permission to use it as much. If your **ONLY** goal is to store some data, then SQL-driven database is a sure overkill.

Comment: Thank you for your help!